# The cpp statements included in the haskell code don't work

Tags: haskell, c-preprocessor, ghc, cabal

I'm using the **{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}** pragma in Haskell, however, the cpp statements included in the haskell code don't work for me: The compiler gives me the following error when I run stack install:

```
error: parse error on input '#'.
```

Any suggestions?

This is a sample of the code I am using with GHC version 8.4.3:

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}
  ...
  #if MIN_VERSION_base(4,9,0)
  import Data.Functor.Classes
  #endif
```

Comment: What command do you run to get that error?

Comment: The error occurs when I execute any the following command: stack install

Comment: **cpp code must be unindented**. In my case, while the Haskell code indentation was correct, the c++ statement within the Haskell code must be unindented.

Comment: Thank you DanielWagner and @ThomasM.DuBuisson for the support. The problem has been solved.

Comment: As long as the `#` is on the first column the text that follows (e.g. `if MIN_VERSION ...`) can be indented as much as you like, which can be useful for readability

Comment: @RacielHernand Could you make a proper answer, so other people might easier find it and learn from it as well?

Comment: Thank you @glennsl. It was ready, a summary of the solution was added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**cpp statement inside code haskell must be unindented.**

> In my case, while the Haskell code indentation was correct, the c++
>   statement within the Haskell code must be unindented.

I simply took the code line from cpp to zero indentation. The rest of the Haskell code stays the same.

Code corrected:

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}
  ...
#if MIN_VERSION_base(4,9,0)
  import Data.Functor.Classes
  ...
#endif
```

Best regards.